# How to prove that $\sup|\int_{(0,1)}\ \cos(tx)dt| < \frac{1}{1+n} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Given the function: $$ f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}x,\qquad\qquad x\in\mathbb R^*$$ and $f(0)=1$.

I have shown that$$f(x) = \int_{(0,1)}\ \cos(tx)dt $$
and that  $$f∈ C^{\infty}(\mathbb R).$$

The next question is to prove that $$\sup|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{1+n}.$$
Here is my try: let $g(t,x) = \cos(tx)$, we know that since $g∈ C^{\infty}([0,1]\times \mathbb R)$, $f∈ C^{\infty}(R)$ and $$f^{(n)}(x) = \int_{(0,1)}\ \frac{\partial^n g(t,x)}{\partial x^n }dt,$$
I found that: for n odd $$f^{(n)}(x)= -t^n\sin(tx) ,$$
so $|t^n\sin(tx)|<t^n<1$   since $0<t<1$.
And
for n even  $$f^{(n)}= t^n\cos(tx).$$
But I have no idea on how to continue from here. Any help please?

Comment: The title needs to be repaired. You are doing the right thing except that you wrote down $\partial^n g/\partial x^n$ and said you were writing down $f^{(n)}$.

Comment: May be $|t^n\cos tx|\leq t^n$ and Integrate from 0 to 1 and get the inequality

Comment: You tried to fit too much int9 your title and ended up with a completely unhelpful title.

Answer (score 2):

For all $t\in\mathbb R$, you have $\displaystyle\left|\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}[\cos(tx)]\right|\leqq|t|^n$ since
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}[\cos(tx)]\right|
&=
\begin{cases}
|t|^n|\sin(tx)|&\mathrm{if}\quad n : \mathrm{odd}\\
|t|^n|\cos(tx)|&\mathrm{if}\quad n : \mathrm{even}
\end{cases}
&\leqq|t|^n.
\end{align}

Thus, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, you have
\begin{align}
|f^{(n)}(x)|
&=\left|\int_0^1\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}[\cos(tx)]\ dt\right|\\
&\leqq\int_0^1\left|\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}[\cos(tx)]\right|dt\\
&\leqq\int_0^1 t^n dt \\
&=\frac{1}{1+n}.
\end{align}
Therefore $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f^{(n)}(x)|\leqq\frac{1}{1+n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The expressions you found for the derivatives are missing the integrals. What you have is
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\int_0^1t^ng_n(tx)\,dt,
$$
where $$g_n(t)=\begin{cases}\pm \sin t,&\ n\ \text{even,}\\ \pm\cos t,&\ n\ \text{odd}\end{cases}
$$
So
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)|≤\int_0^1t^{n}\,dt=\frac1{n+1}.
$$